# redirect to www. in a protected folder with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi I've got a password protected folder on a UNIX server on my site and an htaccess file with non-www. redirect to www. but for some reason I can't make it work for the protected folder. I've tried adding the code to the htaccess file in the protected folder but it doesn't work the server just returns a 401 Authorisation Required error and won't accept any user and password. 
Any ideas how to get it to work?

for example. 
http://domain.net/password-protect/good-url.php
returns a 401 error page while:
http://domain.net/subfolder/good-url.php
doesn't

Here's the htaccess code in the root folder:
Code1.

```
RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
 RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And in my password protected folder:
Code2.

```
  AuthName "Ins"
  AuthUserFile "/home6/gingerc3/.htpasswds/public_html/password-subfolder/passwd"
  AuthType Basic
  require valid-user
```

I tried tagging on Code1. to Code2. but it doesn't work. The www. rewrite works fine in other subfolders but not the password protected ones.

By the way, adding on the following code to Code2. does work. 
Code3.

```
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /password-protect/bad-url.php http://www.domain.net/password-protect/good-url.php
```

Thanks.

Comment: In the first code, both rule sets do the same job of www redirection. You can safely remove one of them. The only difference is that the first one only works for requests to 443 port, but the second one works for both http and https.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply, I'm new to forum and didn't see your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. To be honest. I didn't really understand these codes and I added the first part of the Code1. because someone suggested I do so. Looking at it I don't know why I should be using server port 443 so that was the first alert to me to maybe remove that part. I scrapped all the code, and used the hosts helper app. to create a wildcard redirect and instead of using subfolders I've essentially replaced the "/" in an address with "." in file names, now everything is in the same folder and used the htaccess file to password protect all files starting with what used to be the folder name.

```
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.net$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]

<Files file-name.*>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/home6/user/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
</Files>
```

It works perfectly now. Tip: if you change the htaccess file you might get an error the first time you check it. Try refreshing the page first.